# Macro without having to select and CtrlC

Tags: excel, vba

This macro works only when I select and ctrl C rows from A22-78.
I want it to work without me having to do so. 
This function makes one column out of (#rows)*(#columns in each row)

```
Sub RowsToColumn()
Dim RN As Range
Dim RI As Range
Dim r As Long
Dim LR As Long
Dim WS As Worksheet
Set WS = Sheets.Add
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Columns(1).Insert
r = 0
LR = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For Each RN In Range("B22:B" & LR)
    r = r + 1
    For Each RI In Range(RN, Range("XFD" & RN.Row).End(xlToLeft))
        r = r + 1
        Cells(r, 1) = RI
        RI.Clear
    Next RI
Next RN
Columns("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Delete Shift:=xlUp
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Thank u

Answer (score 1):

I tried out your code, and what it appears to do is to read the values from left to right and place them all in column A in respective order. 
Can this help:

```
Sub Test()

Dim oRange          As Range
Dim oSheet          As Excel.Worksheet
Dim vArray()        As Variant

Dim lCnt_A          As Long
Dim iCnt_B          As Integer
Dim lCnt_C          As Long
Dim iCnt_Cols       As Integer


Set oSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)

Columns(1).Insert
Set oRange = oSheet.UsedRange
iCnt_Cols = oRange.Columns.Count

vArray = oRange
oRange.ClearContents

For lCnt_A = 1 To UBound(vArray)
    For iCnt_B = 1 To iCnt_Cols
        lCnt_C = lCnt_C + 1
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Cells(lCnt_C, 1).Value = vArray(lCnt_A, iCnt_B)

    Next iCnt_B
Next lCnt_A

Set oSheet = Nothing
Set oRange = Nothing

End Sub
```

Please tell me if I got your intentions wrongly.